# Iterating and modifying a low triangle table with empty upper values

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

Given the triangle matrix I have in excel:

```
        Random    Name    ValC    ValA
Random
Name      1     
ValC      3      7     
ValA      4      10       20
```

I wish to be able to implement my own order (Not necessary as tuple) and create another triangle matrix:

```
order = (ValA, Random, ValC, Name)

        ValA    Random    ValC    Name
ValA
Random    4     
ValC      20      3     
Name      10      1       7
```

Also, I wish to be able to play with the header names on my convenience:

```
dict = {'ValA':'Files','Random':'Num', 'ValC':'Restr', 'Name':'Course'}

        Files    Num    Restr    Course
Files
Num      4     
Restr    20      3     
Course   10      1       7
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with transpose DataFrame, then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and set upper triangle to `NaN`s by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), last `rename` index and columns by dictionary:

```
order = ('ValA', 'Random', 'ValC', 'Name')
#dont use dict like variable name, because python code word (builtin) 
d = {'ValA':'Files','Random':'Num', 'ValC':'Restr', 'Name':'Course'}

#if necessary replace empty strings to missing values
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
mask = np.triu(np.ones(df.shape)).astype(np.bool)
df1 = (df.combine_first(df.T)
         .reindex(index=order, columns=order)
         .mask(mask)
         .rename(columns=d, index=d))

print (df)
        Files  Num  Restr  Course
Files     NaN  NaN    NaN     NaN
Num       4.0  NaN    NaN     NaN
Restr    20.0  3.0    NaN     NaN
Course   10.0  1.0    7.0     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks!. I got this error: Array conditional must be the same shape as self (Line 17 .mask(mask))

Comment: @gusa10 - What is `print (df.shape)` ?

Comment: Same error. I have some columns which are numbers too. Does this influence? Sorry I am naive with numpy

Comment: I think if comment my solution and test `print (df.shape)`, what it return?

Comment: same error: ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self...line 17, in <module>  .mask(mask)

Comment: @gusa10 - Are data confidental?

Comment: sorry. there was an missing column 26 in my data and the shape was (25,26). Now I add an empty cell and my data has a shape of (26,26). The error now is : sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  return this.join(other, how=how, return_indexers=return_indexers)
(26, 26)

Comment: @gusa10 - You need same index and columns names, is it in real data? `print (df.index)` and `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: your were right. I had changed the dtype now as `df.index = df.index.astype(np.int64)` and `df.columns = df.columns.astype(np.int64)`. My dictionary is like  `d = {1:'order1', 2:'order2', 3:'order3',..} `.Now the df1 is ordered but all the values are  `NaN `

Comment: @gusa10 - Check my profile, there is my email (need run code in profile for email :))

Comment: I have modified my previous answer. Sorry the message is still the same `FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison  return bool(asarray(a1 == a2).all())` and all the values in the dataframe are `NaN`

Comment: I found the error. It is because the index = order is trying to change np.int64 for str. The simply solution would be adding `.rename(columns=d, index=d)` before reindexing the data. It worked!